# How to use radio type as button without submit form?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I use radio type button in my form:

```
<div class="d-block">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="radio" name="type" value="rent" style="padding-right: 0 !important;" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary pr-4 pl-0 active" id="left">{{ __('Rent') }}</button>
    <button type="radio" name="type" value="buy" style="padding-right: 0 !important;" class="btn btn-lg btn-light pr-4 pl-0" id="right">{{ __('Sale') }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to change between Rent and Buy button without Submit Form ?

Comment: That HTML is invalid. Buttons can't have a type of radio. It will therefore default to the button's default type, submit.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be `input` and not `button`

```html
<div class="d-block">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="rent" style="padding-right: 0 !important;" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary pr-4 pl-0 active" id="left">{{ __('Rent') }}</input>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="buy" style="padding-right: 0 !important;" class="btn btn-lg btn-light pr-4 pl-0" id="right">{{ __('Sale') }}</input>
  </div>
</div>
```